# Join dataframes by column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, inner-join

I have two data frames `df1` and `df2` taken from different databases. Each item in the dataframes is identified by an `id`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,20,30,50,100,110],'cost':[100,0,300,570,400,140]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,23,30,58,100,110],'name':['a','b','j','d','k','g']})
```

there are some common products in both dataframes, in this case those with the ids:   10,30,100,110. 
I want to merge this information in one single dataframe, as this one:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[10,30,100,110],'name':['a','j','k','g'],'cost':[100,300,400,140]})
```

I was trying to do it with dictionaries and nested loops but I handling a rather big amount of data and it just take to long to do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html), default parameter `how='inner'` is omited:

```
print (pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id'))
   cost   id name
0   100   10    a
1   300   30    j
2   400  100    k
3   140  110    g
```

Comment: I'm not getting the same result. I update the question.

Comment: It looks like typo - double `df2` `print (pd.merge(df2,df2,on='id'))`